# <ul> items overflowing from nav

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow

this is my very first post on this site, so excuse me if I'm not clear enough.

I'm currently working on a  [website](http://linda-navarro-coaching.com/) built using wordpress, and I have an issue with CSS.

My menu bar is made with an ul, and, when I increase text size in my navigator (with ctrl+scroll for example), li items overflow from the div, like in [this image](http://lindanavarrocoaching.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/bug.jpg).

In this case, I would like the li to be splitted in two part, and fit in the div, but I did not find how to realize that. I've already tried the "word-break" solution, but I guess I was doing it wrong.

Because my site is hosted by Wordpress, there are two different CSS sheets used for the design, which is a bit messy.

Here is a part of my sheet :

```
#access {
display:inline-block;
width:27%;
font-size:100%;
margin:2.5% auto 6px;
border:none;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
overflow:hidden;}

#access a {
display:inline-block;
max-width:100%;
color:rgb(0,102,138);
font-size:22px;
padding:none;
line-height:30px;}

#access li {
display:block;
padding:4px;
float:none;}

#access ul {
list-style:none;
font-size:100%;
margin:0;}
```

I can't post the theme's CSS link because, as a new member, I'm limited to 2 hyperlinks by post.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These menu items contain non-breaking spaces.:

Coaching professionnel

Coaching parental

```
Coaching&nbsp;professionnel
Coaching&nbsp;parental
```

This means when text increases in size they will all remain on one line.

Also, your #access has overflow:hidden; Remove that, and remove the non-breaking spaces - ("&nbsp") and your words should wrap correctly

Comment: You're right, thank you for your answer.

I've fixed this. However, now, when a li is splitted, the text on the second line isn't totally centered in the div. 

Do you know how to center it perfectly?

Comment: "&ensp;" is included in the width calculation of each line, so each line centres beginning at &ensp; and ending at the last letter of the line, making the centre appear off. If you remove these html entities each line will centre correctly.